# Android Webview Redirect loop

Tags: android, webview

I have a Webview in my project.

Some pages link to other pages with javascript.

ie. I click on link 1 which links to page 2. In page 2 javascript redirects to page 3.

In page 3 I capture onBackpress and check if the webview cangoback. If it can, I call webview.goBack().

But doing so opens page 2, which in turns automatically redirects to page 3. Making it hard for the user to exit the activity.

Does anyone know how to prevent redirect loops?

Answer (score 0):

Use location.replace(url) instead of location.href=url. or give some delay before redirection.